# How to get the words from a line of String

Tags: java

A line of `"IMPORT halfadder fulladder"` is passed in to method's parameter. How can I get the words `halfadder` and `fulladder` from that line? THe passed `String line` always contains the word `IMPORT` as the first token and is followed either by `halfadder` or `fulladder` of `both` `(halfadder and fulladder)`. I do not know how to get those words after the word `IMPORT`

```
public void parseImportLine(String line)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for String.split

Comment: Will your string always be `"IMPORT halfadder fulladder"`?  Or is it possible that some other strings might be passed in?  If it's possible, then what's the exact purpose of this method: to look for the next two words, look for all words, look for words ending in `adder`, or what?  It's important that you learn to ask questions that cover all possible inputs, not just one example.  I firmly believe that without that skill, one can never be a good programmer.

Comment: @ajb, the String which is passed always contains the word IMPORT first, then it is followrd by either halfadder or fulladder or both.

Comment: So there are only 3 possible inputs? `"IMPORT halfadder fulladder"`, `"IMPORT fulladder"` or `"IMPORT halfadder"`? In that case you don't need to split the string, you can just switch on the value.

Comment: @pbabcdefp probably 4 inputs: `"IMPORT fulladder halfadder"` would be one, equivalent to `"IMPORT halfadder fulladder"`.  Of course I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the string by splitting them into an array and ignore the word `IMPORT` and print the rest(or add in new print, anyway you want to do it)

```
public static void parseImportLine(String line)
{
    String[] word = line.split("\\s+");

    for(int i=0;i<= word.length-1;i++)
      {
        if (!(word[i].equals("IMPORT")))
        {
          System.out.println(word[i]);
        }
       }
}
```

Here is an [Working example](https://ideone.com/bb4FJf)

Let me know, if this didn't help.

Comment: WHat does \\s mean ? @TheUknown

Comment: Thats for the `space`

Comment: @Nikolay btw even `line.split(" ")` works. I used `regex` in this case, you dont have to